# Trouble Installing babel's "plugin-proposal-export-default-from"

Tags: python, reactjs, dependencies, babeljs

I'm very new to React/Javascript/dependency stuff so the other answers I've seen for similar questions were not entirely clear to me:

I'm trying to implement a pie chart for my react project as described here: https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/pie-chart/

I created my project with **create-react-app** and then ran **npm install canvasjs** inside.

Then I get the following error when running npm start: **"Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from (https://git.io/vb4yH) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation."**

When looking up the error, I found this website: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from ,which says to run the following command:

**npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from**

This wasn't working (would get a warning about needing to install dependencies), so I read online that to modify Babel, you had to run **npm run eject** and then change the Python path version to 2.7. I did that and now the command works to install the packages.

I found this old discussion where people mention it being a bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7293

They said to change stuff in the babel.config.js file as a solution, but I don't know where that file is located (it doesn't appear when I search it up). I'm on a Mac OS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the file at the same location as your package.json file.

This is how the file contents looks like

```
    /* eslint-disable func-names */
    module.exports = function (api) {
      const presets = [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-flow'
      ];
      const plugins = [
        [
          '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
          {
            loose: true
          }
        ],
        [
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
          {
            loose: true
          }
        ],
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
      ];

      /** this is just for minimal working purposes,
         * for testing larger applications it is
         * advisable to cache the transpiled modules in
         * node_modules/.bin/.cache/@babel/register* */
      api.cache(false);

      return {
        presets,
        plugins
      };
    };
```